# Does the umbraco rest-api return the entire cms content with media?

Tags: umbraco

With Umbraco's rest API, if I make a call to fetch a particular piece of content, will it return the media embedded in the content?

i.e. the text content and also the media like images/video that have URL's that will be served by Umbraco's filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

I think so, according to this article by Marcin Zajkowski on [24days.in Umbraco](https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2015/umbraco-rest-api/) it is based on [HAL (Hypertext Application Language)](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) and the /umbraco/rest/v1/content api returns an _embedded property for Embedded Resources (please note, the article is talking about the 2015 version, [GitHub current version is here](https://github.com/umbraco/UmbracoRestApi)):

"Our embedded items have all the standard JSON properties listed inside of them and of course the HAL Model properties helping to go throught [sic] them to discover other items below them for example. We can easily play with all the items, navigate through them and find or create all what we need."

This has all of the Umbraco properties in it.